# Angular.extend evaluating parameterless functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I am having this weird issue where angular.extend is evaluating my parameterless functions. My `userData` factory is extended from my `applicationUserData`, but the end result is that my userData object in the userData factory has actual values for `needsTraining` and `showWelcomeText` instead of them being functions. The `setUserData(appbaseUserData)` function still shows up as a function. Any idea why this is?

```
application.factory('applicationUserData', [function(){
    var userData;
    return {
        setUserData: function(appbaseUserData){
            userData = appbaseUserData;
        },
        needsTraining: function(){
            userData.ensureUserDataInitialized();
            return userData.needsTraining;
        },
        showWelcomeText: function(){
            userData.ensureUserDataInitialized();
            return userData.showWelcomeText;
        }
    }
}]);

appBaseModule.factory("userData", ["applicationUserData", function(applicationUserData) {
    var userData = {},
        userDataInitialized = false;

    userData.init = function(data) {
        applicationUserData.setUserData(userData);
        angular.extend(userData, applicationUserData, data);
        userDataInitialized = true;
    };
....
    return userData;
}]);
```

Comment: Something must be wrong in data i guess, `angular.extend` is doing fine in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/CQwNq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not `extend` that's doing this.

[Here is the source for that method in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L324)

```js
function extend(dst) {
  var h = dst.$$hashKey;
  forEach(arguments, function(obj){
    if (obj !== dst) {
      forEach(obj, function(value, key){
        dst[key] = value;
      });
    }
  });

  setHashKey(dst,h);
  return dst;
}
```

What's in `data` at the time you're calling it? it's possible that it has some value that it's putting in that overwrites your function.

Either way, it's not `extend` itself. That's a pretty simple function.

Comment: Using version 1.2.4; And if i look at the injected applicationUserData it reads as functions, but they dont survive the extend.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's probably whatever is in `data` that's being passed to your `init` function.